# AppWidget Listview Items with weird height after setting layout_width and height as "match_parent" or "wrap_content"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-appwidget, android-appwidget-list

Currently, I'm trying to create a collection widget using listview with every item equal to the width and height of the 3x2 widget displayed on the screen. The items looked fine when I inputted the layout_width and height as 203dp and 220dp as provided by the android's "Provide flexible widget layout" documentation, as shown below:
[An item in the Listview appwidget when the layout_width and height are inputted as 203dp and 220dp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFcyt.png)
However, by doing so, my widget looks weird on some android phones I've tested on (since the size values were hardcoded), therefore, I tried to switch the layout width and height values into match_parent, yet the item then became like this:
[An item now with weird height after setting the layout width and height as match_parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJgTU.png)
Is there a fix to this? Thank you!
This is the code for my widget item:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widgetBackground"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Widgetvariation.AppWidgetContainer">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/diningBackground"
        android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
        android:clipToOutline="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:foreground="@drawable/white_fade_gradient"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/image_commons" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appwidget_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/appwidget_text"
        android:fontFamily="@font/kollektif"
        android:text="Lauder\nCollege House"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/DiningStatusLabel"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text=" Closed until Wednesday "
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:foreground="@drawable/roundcorner"
        android:clipToOutline="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-75dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_cancel_24" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the code for my widget layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Widgetvariation.AppWidgetContainer"
    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/widgetframe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Widgetvariation.AppWidgetContainer"
        >
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/stackview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:loopViews="true"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="8dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/emptyview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/app_widget_background"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_screen435"
            />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

After some trial and error, I am almost certain that this issue is caused by the layout width and height of my item - considering that in a regular display widget with a singular imageView under a relativelayout, when I set my widget layout and imageView width and heights and match_parent, they fill up the entire 3x2 widget and the pictures were displayed correctly under centerCrop.

Comment: what's your expected layout, could you please share a reference image?